# Varme Tyv in Grimm

Tags: grimm

Someone needs to explain their wacky biology to me, please. My four questions are these.
(The following are spoilers for the 'Hibernaculum' episode of Grimm Season Four)

1. I understand that cold-blooded creatures lose heat, but in the episode with Varme Tyv in it, it wasn't even cold outside, as said by other characters. So how did the Gundersons die and get covered in ice within such a short time?
2. What exactly allows one to suck the heat from your body with a bite?
3. The phrase Varme Tyv means 'Heat Theif' in Swedish and Norwegian. Under the assumption that the Wesen in Grimm are all based on fairy tales, what nordic tale inspired these reptilian creatures?
4. Monroe says that a Varme Tyv could 'freeze to death while sitting next to a campfire' because they only process ***human*** body heat. But they were fine driving in a car. And produced steaming heat when lying together in the hibernaculum. So if the only thing in this world that can warm them is taking heat from humans, then how is the Varme Tyv not extinct?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! We recommend 1 question per question here, so you should probably split this into 4 separate posts.

Comment: I would say questions 1, 2, and 4 are all pretty related, as they ask how the biology of these creatures is supposed to work (it didn't make any sense to me either). Question 3 really should be split into a separate question.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure who felt it necessary to downvote this question, but maybe give new users some leeway if they ask a good question in the wrong way? Otherwise you may drive away new users.

Comment: @varradami - Question 3 was worded poorly, and I apologize. I didn't understand what Brothers Grimm tale could have inspired white snake Wesen from Scandinavia that function like that. A little counterintuitive to have them freeze even in hot climates yet originate from a cold one, don't you think?

Comment: Correction: _varme tyv_ means ‘(the) hot thief’ in Danish and Bokmål Norwegian. It doesn't mean anything in Swedish (it would be _varma tjuv_ there). ‘Heat thief’ would be _varmetyv_ in Danish/Bokmål or _värmetjuv_ in Swedish. The notion of heat-stealers does sound vaguely familiar from some folktale aspect, but I can't remember what it is it’s reminding me of.

Comment: I was searching for an answer to number three as well, as I am 100% Norwegian and have never heard of any being with similar traits as the Varme Tyv. In Norwegian folklore there are only tales about trolls and a boy named Askeladden who's very smart and has a very structured, fast-paced thinking.
As a person generally interested in superstition, I have read the brothers' tales, and I am sure they never wrote anything about this creature. However, I don't have enough knowledge in Swedish or Danish folklore to say that there aren't any tales about the wesen.
I know it isn't much, but I hope it d

Comment: As varradami mentioned, this should probably be split into two questions. #3 could remain here, since there is at least a partial answer for that question below. #1, 2, and 4 could go into a new question.